# Browser back button leads to index page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have web application with spring-security.
To some pages I have configured anonymous access So the flow is like:

indexPage --> firstPage --> secondPage -- thirdPage

To all this pages I can access straight by entering url in browser or by pressing "Next" button on previous page.
However when I click browser back button, I've been redirecting to indexPage doesn't metter in which page I currently stay. How can I avoid such behavior?

Thanks

PS

Next button makes json request

```
$.getJSON("/home/<some_address>.json?mail="+email, function(data) {
            if(data.success)
            { 
                console.log("Data ok!");
                window.location.replace("/home/<next_page>.html?mail="+email);
            }else{
                //handle error
            }
         });
```

Comment: What's exactly doing `Next`button? Does this button make an AJAX request? Is it a link which reloads the whole page and changes the URL in browser? Could you provide some code?

Comment: Next button make json request

$.getJSON("/home/<some_address>.json?mail="+email, function(data) {
   if(data.success)
   { 
    console.log("Data ok!");
    window.location.replace("/home/<next_page>.html?mail="+email);
   }else{
    //handle error
   }
   });

Answer (score 1):

The issue was `window.location.replace()`
should be `window.location = ""`